# Need to custom Decrypt password for System.Data.Entity.DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, encryption

My config has Connection string with encrypted password. Code is using Entity Framework `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` where it holds encrypted password.
How can I customize `System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString` to use decrypted password.

Below code DrcMaster is throwing an erro :Login failed  ( as its trying to use encrypted password)

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Configuration;

namespace DrcAuthentication.Database.User {
    public class UserContext : DbContext
    {
        public UserContext()
        {
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UserContext"].ConnectionString.ToString());
            csb.Password = EncryptionUtils.Decrypt(csb.Password);
            string myCs = csb.ToString();
            Database.Connection.ConnectionString = myCs;
            //db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = myCs;
            this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }

        public DbSet<DrcAuthentication.DrcMaster> DrcMasters { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DrcAuthentication.AuthenticatedUser> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DrcAuthentication.UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
        //public IDbSet<SuperSecured> SuperSecured { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: After decryption, does `myCs` contain a valid connection string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `Database.Connection.ConnectionString` to set the connection string. The `DbContext` class has a constructor that takes in a connection string. You can move the the logic that obtains the connection string and decrypts it to a static method, and then construct the base `DbContext` class from the constructor of `UserContext` like this:

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UserContext"].ConnectionString.ToString());
        csb.Password = EncryptionUtils.Decrypt(csb.Password);
        string myCs = csb.ToString();
        return myCs;
    }

    public UserContext()
        :base(GetConnectionString())
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }



    public DbSet<DrcAuthentication.DrcMaster> DrcMasters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DrcAuthentication.AuthenticatedUser> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DrcAuthentication.UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    //public IDbSet<SuperSecured> SuperSecured { get; set; }

}
```

However, I would recommend that instead of doing this, move the responsibility of obtaining and decrypting the connection string to another class. This leaves the `UserContext` class like this:

```
public class UserContext : DbContext
{
    public UserContext(string connection_string)
        :base(connection_string)
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<DrcAuthentication.DrcMaster> DrcMasters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DrcAuthentication.AuthenticatedUser> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DrcAuthentication.UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    //public IDbSet<SuperSecured> SuperSecured { get; set; }

}
```

Then, another class would inject the decrypted connection string into the `UserContext` class.

Comment: Hi @Naj. If this answer has solved your question, please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.